# Is it possible to get an estimate of the power consumption of a circuit by modeling it with controlled sources?

Tags: operational-amplifier, power, power-measurement

Let's say I have an op-amp. We can measure the power consumption of the circuit by multiplying the current supplied by the voltage supply with the voltage of the voltage supply.

Now, suppose this op-amp is part of a large design and I haven't designed the op-amp circuit yet. Let's say I represent the op-amp with a VCVS. This VCVS has no power supply. Is it possible to estimate the power (say the lower limit of the power) that the op-amp will have when it is finally implemented by multiplying the voltage and current of the VCVS?

Comment: If you replace  an op amp with a VCVS, there will be a modeling violation since the power supply voltage (which is assumed to be an ideal voltage source) will be connected to another ideal voltage source (the VCVCS). Also what voltage will be controlling the VCVS? Why do you think the current drawn by the VCVS will match the current drawn by your op amp?

Comment: If you haven't designed the circuit there's no point other than to guess. A guess would  be as good as anything.

Comment: @Barry, I have a circuit where everything has been designed excepted the amplifier. The amplifier I need is a bidirectional amplifier (amplifies voltage in one direction, and current in another direction). Since I haven't design the bidirectional amplifier yet, I am modelling it with a combination of a VCVC and a CCCS. I want to get an estimate of the power consumption of the circuit. Since the VCVC and a CCCS don't have power rails, does multiplying the voltage and current across/through them give a meaningful estimate of the power consumption?

Answer (score 2):

Your method will estimate the power delivered by the op-amp to its load, but it won't estimate the power consumed by the op-amp itself.

To estimate the power consumed by the op-amp, you can treat it very similarly to a linear regulator, taking the supply current as being approximately equal to the output current. Assuming a positive output voltage, its power consumption is approximately

$$ P = I_{out}\left(V_{cc}-V_{out}\right)$$

where \$I_{out}\$ is the op-amp's output current (taken as positive when flowing out of the output pin), \$V_{cc}\$ is its positive power supply voltage, and \$V_{out}\$ is its output voltage.

If you are attempting a very low power design, you should also consider the power required to support the op-amp's quiescent current.

Comment: In this case, the total power is the sum of the power the power delivered by the op-amp and the power consumed by the op-amp?